# Custom Font JSPDF Angular

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How can I use Custom Fonts for JSPDF in Angular. I have already tried importing the js converted file into the index.html. Tried importing it with:

```
 const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

// Load Montserrat font
doc.addFileToVFS(
  'assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf',
  'Montserrat-Regular'
);
```

None of it worked, maybe someone already imported custom fonts with Angular and JSPDF and can help me.